# Interpreting PIR Sensor Data

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, sensors, infrared

My project is to use a PIR sensor to detect people walking by. I need advice on how to interpret the output data. For example, if one person passes by, the stream of data my sensor outputs might be:

001111100111100100 - where 0 is no motion detected and 1 is motion detected. I need to identify these closely interspersed clusters of 1s as one discrete instance of an object passing in front. There would be long pauses of 0s and then these groupings of 1s and 0s.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Other than storing the previous value and discarding the new one if it's the same?

Comment: What I meant is that due to jitter one instance of an object passing may be represented as three clusters of 1s and 0s. 001111100111100100 is representative of one object passing by. There would be greater gaps of 0s between separate discrete events.

Comment: So then count the duration since the last long run of 0s.